# removing image data from memory

Tags: android

I have to believe there's a way to clear image data from memory once it's no longer required, but despite exhaustive searching I can't find a solution.  Both stack and the google android dev list are full of questions regarding OOM errors, specifically "bitmap size exceeds VM budget", but I still don't see a clear answer.

I understand there are hard memory limits on devices, and I understand it's not realistic to load up and display or cache large amounts of image data, but there should be away to discard data that's no longer required.

For example, imagine this very basic hypothetical app, that emulates a lot of the behavior of the native gallery app:

1. An image gallery that allows the user to peruse images from a remote server.
2. There might be any number of images on that server.
3. The app displays 1 image at a time, and allows a user to go back or forward 1 image at a time through button presses or swiping.
4. There'd be a maximum of 3 images rendered at any one time (so the user can see the one immediately to the left or right of the current image when swiping).  All other image data should be discarded.
5. Images are loaded using URL.openStream and Drawable.createFromStream or BitmapFactory.decodeStream.  Streams are closed appropriately.
6. Images are sized appropriately *on the server* before being fetched.
7. Loading happens in AsyncTasks.  Tasks that are no longer needed (due to moving away from an image with an incomplete task) are cancelled.  Any references in the AyncTask are WeaklyReferenced.
8. When any image is no longer required, it's "cleared" via:

   - getBackground().setCallback(null)
   - Listeners are set to null
   - setImageDrawable/Bitmap(null)
   - removeView

This simple construct, that takes into account all the suggest practices I'm aware of, will inevitably crash with an OOM error at some point.  Using BitmapFactory.Options inSampleSize and inPreferredConfig will delay the inevitable, but not forever, and at the cost of image quality.  In this example, I've used remote images, but the issue exists with images stored in /assets/ or in internal memory, etc.

My feeling is that if we can display X amount of image data at one point, and we take all steps to remove that image data from memory, we should be able to display that same amount of data later, without having to compensate for what has happened before.

With the sheer quantity of questions about this very issue, I'd hope to have a standard solution documented, but if there is one, I can't find it.  I've seen answers posted by Romain Guy, who otherwise seems very generous with his knowledge and active in the community, that say something like "Simple.  Don't use so much memory".  OK.  Tell me how.

I should also mention that System.gc does nothing to help this.  I'm also aware of bitmap.recycle, but unless I'm mistaken this can't be used in this fashion.

Am I missing something fundamental?  Is there a way to discard image data once it's no longer being used?  What is missing from the above to create a simple photo gallery?  Assuming the built-in gallery app uses the framework and not the NDK, I imagine there has to be a way...

TYIA.

/this question has also been posted on the android developer google group list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through my work with [Prime](https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime) I found a few tips, one of which you have not mentioned. When you decode your Bitmaps make sure to use the `inPurgeable` and `inInputShareable` flags in your `BitmapFactory.Options`. That will help a little bit but I would recommend you look at my implementation of image loading in Prime. I use it in all of my products without any memory issues. I have found that 95% of memory problems are from the incorrect usage of the `Bitmap` class.

Comment: i've found that most 3rd party loaders force the use of RGB_565 decoding, which looks kind of terrible for some images...  does your class allow ARGB_8888?  Do you have any sample usage (I don't see any samples on your repo, besides the one 2-liner - although the javadocs are helpful, some common samples would be great).  Thanks.

Comment: I don't force a format. The examples are in the subfolder labeled 'examples'. They are also on Google Play.

Comment: I'm interested in using your class but have some questions - do you have any plans to expand the docs?  it looks like there's no listener mechanism (but I think you can extend and override onImageReceived, which is nice but not quite as flexible).  also it looks like it's limited to the RemoteImageView, and does not have a separate loading mechanism (which would be handy when supplying bitmaps or drawable to stuff other than ImageViews) - am I missing some stuff?

Comment: The main api is using the Request interface with the ImageManager, the RemoteImageView is just a helper widget for easy integration.

Comment: so something like ImageManager.getInstance(context).get(new ImageManager.Request(){// overrides });

Comment: ok last questions (stacks yelling at me to go into chat for excessive comments) - how would one go about setting decoding options, from RGB565 to ARGB8888 for example?  And is there built-in funcationality to enable or disable caching?  Single-tier or two-tier?  Thanks again - the google-libs imageloader is a little wonky, and the universal image loader has a strange license, so i'd love to find a good general image loader class.  any plans on expanding docs in the future?  i'd be happy to help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10721/discussion-between-handlerexploit-and-big-momo)

Answer (score -1):

There is a very [detailed article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) about the use of bitmaps on the android developer website.
Did you look at it ? 
It explains how to load, cache and display bitmaps efficently and how to get rid of this famous OutofMemoryError.

There is also [a sample application](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip) from an image gallery.
I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I've read that/those article/s - it explains how to do it with large bitmaps (not applicable), how to do it outside of the UI thread (which I'm already doing), how to cache (not applicable) and how to render off-screen (already doing).  Again, I can *avoid* the error using "tricks" but the question is "how to remove that image from memory".  Thanks for the comment.